# Check how many domains are hosted on a linux server (server side)

Tags: linux

How do I check from server side/using bash shell how many domains are hosted on the server?

The goal is to discover how many domains are hosted on the server that are exposed via http/https. (Can be connected to remotely)

I know I can cat /etc/hosts and use the dig command but is there another way to enmurate how many domains are on a given server that I have shell access to?

Comment: *"... I can cat /etc/hosts ..."* - one can host a domain without putting in in /etc/hosts. *"...use the dig command..."* - how? Basically you need to know which domains point to any of the servers IP addresses or to some of  an upstream load balancer/reverse proxy and which are actually configured locally. You might check the server configuration files but these often contain default settings in case a not explicitly domain is used or wildcards for subdomain so you don't know for sure which domains are actually used with this server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have discovered one domain hosted on the server. I guess I'll have to list all possible sub domains and ping them, was hoping there is a more efficient approach server side, thanks.

Comment: *"...and ping them...."* - with a catch-all DNS entry these subdomains will resolve all to the same IP address. If your idea of "being hosted" is that you can ping that my be sufficient but usually "hosted" is used in the context of having a website with this domain. And just because you can ping does not mean that there it is configured in the web server and just because it might be configured at the web server does not mean it has a valid certificate for https etc. So you really need to describe first what you actually want to know.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The goal is to discover how many domains/websites are hosted on a server I have access to, that can be accessed via http/https remotely...

Comment: Suppose you have Bind running on the server (or something else), each hosted 'domain' should have its own zone file. Look in `/var/named/` for example.

Comment: If using bind, here are some pointers [Listing all zones loaded in BIND](https://serverfault.com/q/401024/377666) - [A Bash script to extract a list of domains served by Bind (DNS server)](https://steemit.com/bash/@thomas-tiramisu/a-bash-script-to-extract-a-list-of-domains-served-by-bind-dns-server)

Comment: @drxl_3321: *"that can be accessed via http/https remotely..."* - in this case you need to look at the configuration of the webserver(s) on the system. Note that there might be several on different IP and ports. And you also see (if at all) what the expected domains are there and not what domain might be possible too since everybody might just point its own domain to the IP address of the server. But actually, I don't think this is actually an information security problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on your conversation with @SteffenUllrich in the comments.  I've also edited this answer, following my conversation with @SteffenUllrich after posting it.

You can determine some (but possibly not all) sites that are hosted on the same server as yours, by pointing your browser to the following URL (where x.y.z.0 are the first three octets of the IP address of your server):

```
https://bgp.he.net/net/x.y.z.0/24#_dns
```

Then, click on the DNS tab.  It should display a long table, with IP addresses in the same /24 block as your server in the first column.  Find your server's IP in the list.  Then, in the third column, it should show some (but perhaps not all) of the A records at other domains that point to your server's IP address.

Of course, as Steffen points out, this doesn't mean that the server is actually hosting a site for each of these A records - it merely means that these A records point to your server's IP address.  Anyone can create an A record for a domain that they control, and point it to any IP address that they want.

So, your next step would be to check (either manually using your web browser, or in an automated fashion using some sort of tool) if the web server returns a response that you consider to be valid for a hosted site for each A record in the list.

This method can be used to determine *some* of the sites that are hosted on the same server as yours.  But, there are several caveats, as you can see in the comments following this answer, that may exclude some sites that are hosted on your server from being found using this method.

Comment: This does not give any useful results for me but only an error. Also, how could this system know all A addresses pointing to this site? Is this passive DNS which watches the traffic - in which case it might not see everything possible. Or is this based on PTR records - which even don't exist for many domains. Also, this is 2020 and lots of sites are available by IPv6 too. Apart from that checking for a valid status codes < 400 ignores 401 and 403  which are completely valid responses for a setup. It ignores also setups where the handshake will fail with missing client certificates.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your feedback.  You may need to change the last octet in the IP address to 0.  For example, try https://bgp.he.net/net/8.8.8.0/24#_dns.  I'm sure the data is collected by some sort of crawler, so it may not be complete.  With regard to response status codes, handshake failures, etc., of course this would vary based on what the OP considers to be acceptable for a 'hosted site'.

Comment: It is not clear how the data are collected. Moreover they don't seem to cover any CNAME and thus implicitly omit possible domains.

Comment: Good point about CNAME records.  I've edited my answer to make it clear that this method may not be comprehensive due to the caveats that you mention.